# Removing "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff" header from Google Storage public URL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

My goal is to serve a static `text/javascript` file from Google Storage publicly to include as a script tag.

I'm running into this browser error:

```
"X-Content-Type: nosniff" was given and its Content-Type is not a script MIME type.
```

I curled the Google Storage URL and discovered its 302 redirecting me with the problematic header `X-Content-Type: nosniff` to another link that contains the actual `Content-Type: text/javascript` file.

Is there a way to prevent this redirect on a file made publicly available?

Answer (score 2):

Changing the URL solved the issue of preventing the Google Storage 302 redirect.

from:

```
https://storage.cloud.google.com/<bucket-name>/script.js
```

to:

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/<bucket-name>/script.js
```

Comment: Yep! storage.cloud.google.com is a domain which allows you to authenticate with your Google cookies. As you can imagine, this could lead to a number of cross-site vulnerabilities if it were not very restricted. storage.googleapis.com does not allow cookie authentication and so is significantly more permissive.